# Why won't dynamic onChange function execute?

Tags: jquery, html, dom-events, onchange

I am dynamically creating html elements with jQuery, it's nothing that I haven't done before, but I have a strange bug. I am creating an input element and I want to reregister a change event for it.

```
var label_input = $("<input />", {
         type: 'text',
         change: function() {
           console.log("--");
         }
});
```

When I type something in the input, and then click out of it or hit enter, it should print something to the console. Instead, if I click off of it nothing happens, if I hit enter the element removes itself. I set an event breakpoint for 'change' and in both cases 'change' triggers, but the function is not executed. When I hit enter, I think it registers that as a submit, because the input is in a form, because I get an error message

> GET http://run.plnkr.co/tmXvBwKyliwV5XKS/? 404 (Not Found)

```
function meta_form_generator(elem_id, label, data_update_functions) {
  var form_container = $("<form />", { id: "metaForm", class: elem_id,role: 'form' });
    var label_group = $("<div />",{ class: 'form-group col-xs-6' });
      var label_label = $("<label />",{ text: 'element label:' });
      var label_input = $("<input />",{ 
        type: 'text', 
        class: elem_id + ' form-control',
        placeholder: label,
        change: function(){console.log("---");}
      });
    label_group.append(label_label);
    label_group.append(label_input);
  form_container.append(label_group);
  return form_container;
}
```

I have also tried creating the function I want change to call outside of the initial creation, and I have tried `label_input.change(test_change);`,

When the code above is isolated it seems to work, though hitting enter still causes it to remove itself. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/easilyBaffled/2j8LJ/) But in the context of my project, it has this bug. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AZJzHixl0EhzogJw9OKR?p=preview). This code is in the templates.js file, and it is being called in the Form_Data_Display function in scripts.js. Why won't the on change function execute?

**EDIT** I did a little more poking around and it turned out `$(document).on('change', "."+elem_id, data_update_functions.set_label);` worked, where `elem_id` is an idetifier given to each element in the form, and `data_update_functions.set_label` is a function passed in from outside. But the question still remains why wouldn't the other methods work?

Comment: the change event is only fired if the input field lost the focus try keyUp instead

Comment: Nope, keyup didn't work for me but I did find something else.

Comment: ok and whats your solution?